# Calling an object with two images from a database

Tags: c#, sql, database, image, reference-type

I am trying to replace a stored procedure that calls a single image (as a byte) to a stored procedure that calls two images (as bytes).

The existing call:

```
public byte[] GetSinglePicture(int themeId)
{
    return
        this.connectionStrings.Connection()
            .Single<byte[]>(
                "abc.GetPictureOne", themeId == 0 ? null : new { ThemeId = themeId });
}
```

The new call:

```
public WebsiteLayout GetPictures(int themeId)
{
    return this.connectionSettings.Connection()
        .Single<WebsiteLayout>("abc.GetPictures", themeId == 0 ? null : new { ThemeId = themeId });
}
```

where "WebsiteLayout" is a class and contains the variables:

```
public byte[] PictureOne {get; set;}
public byte[] PictureTwo {get; set;}
```

I have successfully pulled an image from the database using the first call, but since turning the call into a reference call, the pictures do not show when called.

The stored procedure for the first call:

```
create procedure [abc].[GetPictures]
    @themeId int = null
with execute as owner
as
begin
    if @themeId is null
    begin
        select PictureOne
        from   def.tableOfPictures
        where  defaultPicture = 1
    end
    else
    begin
        select PictureOne
        from   def.tableOfPictures
        where  themeId = @ThemeId
    end
end
```

The stored procedure for the second call:

```
create procedure [abc].[GetPictures]
    @ThemeId int = null
with execute as owner
as
begin
    if @ThemeId is null
    begin
        select PictureOne              'PictureOne', 
               PictureTwo              'PictureTwo'
        from   def.tableOfPictures    
        where  defaultPicture = 1
    end
    else
    begin
        select PictureOne               'PictureOne',
               PictureTwo               'PictureTwo
        from   def.tableOfPictures
        where  themeId = @ThemeId
    end
end
```

I use a controller to pass in the theme Id to get the bytes of each picture in a class, and then convert those to a file. I then show the file content, the picture, in the view. This works perfectly when calling one image, but breaks completely when calling two. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Can you clarify, where did you turn the call into a reference call?

Comment: Does method 'GetPictures' return you filled object 'WebsiteLayout', or does it empty all the time?

Comment: The first example is the call I used previously, which called a value-type. I want to use the second example, which calls a reference type.

Comment: As far as I can tell it is empty all the time.

Comment: you are wrong, all you methods returned reference typed output. All arrays are reference typed.

Comment: if it is empty, then correct your linq query, I cannot help, because it is not clear to me what you are using there, what is 'this'?

Comment: Great point rudym, they are both reference types. My mistake.

Comment: 'this' and 'connectionStrings' just refers to the connection to the database